# why user become undefined when I navigate from different page to dashboard in ejs (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, session, navigation

User become undefined when I navigate from the another page.

I'm Sending id of the user from login page to dashboard using session

```
req.session.isAuth = true;
req.session.user = user;
const userData = await register.findById({ _id: user._id });
res.render("./donorpanel/donor_dashboard", { user: userData });
```

userData contains the all the data of the user like id, username etc.

```
<span class="user">
    <%= user.id %>
</span>
```

Error :user is undefined at eval(in ejs templet)

I Created routes with session(isAuth) middleware

```
router.get("/donor_dashboard", isAuth.donorAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render("./donorpanel/donor_dashboard");
});

router.get("/donation", isAuth.donorAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render("./donorpanel/donation");
});
```

The folder structure of user panel is 1. donor_dashboard, 2. donation

Initially when user logged into the dashboard the user's id was displayed perfeclty.

But when user navigate from donation page to dashboard user become undefined.

Error :
user is not defined
at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\Digen More\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:673:12), :15:26)

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve]. We don't know what `console.log(userData)` logs or what the value of `user` is and if the problem has something to do with how `user` is defined then you haven't shown us the code that defines it.

Answer (score 1):

Your EJS page gets the data you pass to it.

It doesn't get all the data in the session.

---

> ```
> res.render("./donorpanel/donor_dashboard", { user: userData });
> ```

Here you pass `userData` to donor_dashboard.ejs.

---

> ```
> res.render("./donorpanel/donor_dashboard");
> ```

You use the same EJS file in a different place, but this time, when you render it, you don't pass it any data at all.

If there is no data at all then `user` is going to be `undefined`.

Comment: So how to get user data in all the pages inside user's panel?

Comment: Read it from the session and pass it via the second argument of `render`.